# Solve $\displaystyle{z=\frac{p^2+q^2}{2}+(p-x)(q-y)}$ using charpits method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$\displaystyle{z=\frac{p^2+q^2}{2}+(p-x)(q-y)}$$

My progess :
I have found the auxiliary equation and found the relation $p=x+a$.
But while finding $q$

$$q(q+2a)=2z+2ay-(x+a)^2$$

Is there no other way to solve without using quadratic formula?

Comment: What is $a$? The equation is entirely symmetric if you exchanged $x$ with $y$ everywhere, so if you found different looking equations for $p$ vs $q$ you did it incorrectly.

Comment: @NinadMunshi a is integration constant .yes,the equation is symmetrical we can take q=y+b also which leads to same equation in p.

Comment: @Gonçalo yes,I think it works but if we use dz=Pdx+qdy then we get 3 constants but if we directly substitute it works

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4848284/charpits-method-of-differential-equations/4863816#4863816, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4751226/find-the-complete-integral-of-following-partial-differential-equation-z-p2?noredirect=1&lq=1.