# Find the complete integral of following partial differential equation $z=(p^2 + q^2)/2 + (p-x)(q-y)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Solve by Charpit's method (find Complete Integral or CI): $\left(p^2+q^2\right)/2 + (p-x)(q-y)=z$

I tried writing down the Charpit's auxillary equations as follows:

$$\frac{dx}{y-p-q}=\frac{dy}{x-q-p}=\frac{dz}{something}=\frac{dp}{y-p-q}=\frac{dq}{x-p-q}$$

I have chosen 1st and fourth fraction and got $p$=$x$+a.a is chosen as arbitrary constant.Now using original quationa nd this value of p .I am getting horrible q value .I am not able to simply ${dz}=p{dx}+q{dy}$ expression.I absolutely have no idea how to proceed at this step.

Would someone please help me to solve this?

PS : Here $p = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $q = \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving
$$
\frac{dy}{x-q-p}=\frac{dq}{x-p-q} \tag{1}
$$
one finds $q=y+b$. Plugging this result and $p=x+a$ into $dz=pdx+qdy$, one obtains
$$
dz=(x+a)dx+(y+b)dy \implies z=\frac{1}{2}(x+a)^2+\frac{1}{2}(y+b)^2+c. \tag{2}
$$
Comparing $(2)$ with the PDE $z=\frac{1}{2}(p^2 + q^2) + (p-x)(q-y)$, one concludes that $c=ab$, hence the final solution is
$$
z=\frac{1}{2}(x+a)^2+\frac{1}{2}(y+b)^2+ab. \tag{3}
$$

Comment: yes, your answer is correct. Above problem was  part of bigger question which asked to find integral surface passing through  x axis.I used your solution and got correct answer.
one doubt - isn't it necessary to calculate q value using given equation  by putting p value calculated from first fraction. I see most problems in charpit's in my tutorial sheet is solved where p or q is calculated from charpit's equation and second p or q by putting in equation.