# Charpit's method of Differential equations.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Solve the given non-linear differential equation using charpit's method:
$$Z = \frac{p^2+q^2}{2}+(p-x)(q-y)$$

my work:

After writing charpit's auxilliary equation, I equated the fractions twice and solved them and got $p=x+a$ and $q=y+b$ (a and b are constants) and I have verified them, they are correct.

**Doubt**:

Now what i have to do next ?

**should I directly out these values of p and q in $dz= pdx +qdy$** or **should i put one of the(p or q) in the original differential equation and then solve it to get p(or q).** As per the steps mentioned in the book(**attachment**), I should go with the 2nd approach but i don't think it's the correct way forward.

**attachment**

> [image: Charpit's rule]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the complete integral of following partial differential equation $z=(p^2 + q^2)/2 + (p-x)(q-y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4751226/find-the-complete-integral-of-following-partial-differential-equation-z-p2)

Comment: @Gonçalo The person has same doubt, but his doubt is never cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods give the same result. The first method, which I used in [Find the complete integral of following partial differential equation $z=(p^2 + q^2)/2 + (p-x)(q-y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4751226/find-the-complete-integral-of-following-partial-differential-equation-z-p2?noredirect=1&lq=1), gives the following result:
$$
z=\frac{1}{2}(x+a)^2+\frac{1}{2}(y+b)^2+ab. \tag{1}
$$
Now, let's use the second method. Integrating $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=p=x+a$, we find
$$
z=\frac{x^2}{2}+ax+f(y), \tag{2}
$$
hence $q=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=f'(y)$. Substituting these expressions for $z, p,$ and $q$ in the PDE, we obtain
$$
\frac{x^2}{2}+ax+f(y)=\frac{1}{2}(x+a)^2+\frac{1}{2}(f'(y))^2+a(f'(y)-y)
$$
$$
\implies (f'(y)+a)^2=2f(y)+2ay \implies \frac{f'(y)+a}{\sqrt{2f(y)+2ay}} = \pm 1
$$
$$
\implies \sqrt{2f(y)+2ay}=\pm (y +c) \implies f(y)=\frac{1}{2}(y+c)^2-ay. \tag{3}
$$
Substituting $(3)$ in $(2)$, and defining $b:=c-a$, we finally obtain
\begin{align}
z&=\frac{x^2}{2}+ax+\frac{1}{2}(y+a+b)^2-ay \\
&=\frac{1}{2}(x+a)^2+\frac{1}{2}(y+b)^2+ab, \tag{4}
\end{align}
which is identical to $(1)$.